# Applying spline interpolation for Brunt-Vaisala frequency

Tags: python, matplotlib, metpy

I have taken an upper air sounding from [UWYo Database](https://weather.uwyo.edu/upperair/sounding.html) and currently calculating the Brunt-Vaisala frequency (the 'squared' one, at the moment) using MetPy across several stations for some basic synoptic purposes.

The minimal (at some point) and reproducible code runs like this;

```
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from metpy.units import units, pandas_dataframe_to_unit_arrays
from siphon.simplewebservice.wyoming import WyomingUpperAir

stations = ['RPLI', 'RPUB', '98433', 'RPMP', 'RPVP', 'RPMD'] #6 stations
station_data = {}
date = datetime(2016, 8, 14, 0)

for station in stations:
    print(f'Getting {station}')
    df = pandas_dataframe_to_unit_arrays(WyomingUpperAir.request_data(date, station))
    df['theta'] = mpcalc.potential_temperature(df['pressure'], df['temperature'])
    df['bv_squared'] = mpcalc.brunt_vaisala_frequency_squared(df['height'], df['theta'])
    station_data[station] = df

mean_bv = []
for station in stations:
    df = station_data[station]
    keep_idx = (df['height'] >= 1000 * units.m) & (df['height'] <= 5 * units.km)
    mean_bv.append(np.mean(df['bv_squared'][keep_idx]).m)

plt.title("Atmospheric Stability")
plt.plot(mean_bv)
plt.show()
```

which produces a simple plot like this

[image]

I would like to ask for help on how to smooth out those 'lines'/data, like by applying interpolation producing a smooth curve? I'm a bit novice, thus I look forward to your help and responses.

Comment: By "smoothing", do you mean making the graph less jagged by adding additional points? Or do you mean modifying the original data points to reduce how much they vary?

Comment: Hello. By modifying the original data points on how they change. Perhaps similar to an interpolation (interp1d? or something?).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you're looking for is to smooth or (low-pass) filter the data.

One option is to fit the data points to some kind of appropriate curve (polynomial, spline, exponential, etc.), and replace the original data values with with those computed from the curve. You can look at some of the tools in [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) to do the fit.

For filtering, there are a variety of options, from a moving average to more traditional filters; for this a good simple Savitzky-Golay filter. [`scipy.signal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) has a lot of tools to help you with this.